# How to use warmupTrigger in Python V1 azure function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I'm confused by how to actually use a Python warmup trigger in Python V1 functions. My understanding is:

- follow the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-warmup?tabs=isolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4&pivots=programming-language-python) (except don't use the function name "warmup" as it says, use "main" as it shows in the example)
- remove the type hint because [it is a bug](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/62804#issuecomment-1180075019)
- it only works on "premium" (now elastic premium and dedicated?) but definitely not on consumption plans

We are on the Elastic Premium plan.

However, when I do all this and try all sorts of permutations (adding different various configs, etc) I can never get the warmup trigger to actually work. When I view the execution count for the warmup function it shows 0 even with scaling events. When I query the logs with:

```
requests
| project
    timestamp,
    id,
    operation_Name,
    success,
    resultCode,
    duration,
    operation_Id,
    cloud_RoleName,
    invocationId=customDimensions['InvocationId']
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| where cloud_RoleName =~ 'efwusprodfunc04' and operation_Name =~ 'warmup'
| order by timestamp desc
| take 20
```

It shows nothing. When I query the logs for the info log it should have from the warmup trigger, nothing.

So I don't think the warmup trigger is actually working. It also seems like there can be some cold-start issues if it scales out quickly.

- Is there somewhere else I should look in logs to see if it's actually working?
- Is there something I'm missing with how to set up a warmupTrigger in Python V1 azure functions programming model?
- Does warmupTrigger even work any more?
- Is there something else I should change in logging configs so I can see the logs from the warmupTrigger, which are from python logging?

Answer (score 0):

This is incredibly frustrating, but the directory/folder the warmupTrigger function is in (and hence the function name) should be called "warmup". Anything else and it won't work. This is technically in the instructions, but is confusing because they say the function must be called warmup. It wasn't clear if this "function" is the azure function or Python function. The python function must be called "main".

The other requirements above still hold:

- must be elastic premium or dedicated plan (not consumption)
- must remove the type hint from the example

I also added the scriptFile entry in function.json to make sure it was using the right script file.

I was able to see it worked from querying the logs for the message "Function App instance is warm.", and from the above logs query I put in the question. Clicking into the function and looking at invocations shows 0 though, which is obviously incorrect. Some bug in MS's monitoring logging for warmupTrigger I guess.